# Add custom link as a sub menu, below WooCommerce in Admin Area

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add a custom link as a submenu, below WooCommerce, under "Orders". [image]

I've tried using the following code, but I'm missing something. How do I add a custom link?

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');

function register_my_custom_submenu_page() {
add_submenu_page( 'woocommerce', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 'My Custom Submenu Page', 
'manage_options', 'my-custom-submenu-page', 'my_custom_submenu_page_callback' ); 
}

function my_custom_submenu_page_callback() {
echo '<h3>My Custom Submenu Page</h3>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to add a custom link, under WooCommerce:

```
// Adding custom sub menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_link_into_appearnace_menu');
function add_custom_link_into_appearnace_menu() {
global $submenu;
$permalink = 'http://www.cusomtlink.com';
$submenu['woocommerce'][] = array( 'POS Orders', 'manage_options', $permalink );
}
```